# Connecting USB devices to wireless network

Tags: networking, usb, router, hardware-rec, wireless-router

I had been using a Desktop computer at home to connect USB devices at home to.

I am looking to just buy a wireless router that will let me connect a printer and hard drives to it.  I should be able to use a USB hub to do that.

Does anybody have any recommendations on that?  I know the Netgear router with USB is only for hard drives, but am hoping somebody has a good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I've only heard of printer sharing and file sharing - it sounds like you're aware of a file sharing router but you want something else.

Comment: As whitequark points out, many routers are based on linux. Third party firmware projects and compatable routers can be used for file and printer sharing. Of course this requires that the linux running on the router have appropriate drivers and servers and that the end user computer have appropriate client software to make use of the device.

Answer (score 1):

Routers with USB port (sometimes even with two ports) are not uncommon; I know about [TP-Link TL-WR1043ND](http://www.tp-link.com/products/productDetails.asp?class=&content=spe&pmodel=TL-WR1043ND), and also ASUS WL500 series. Both of them are internally running Linux and can do both of tasks you need (file and printer sharing).

I won't recommed Asus one, through, as it only has USB 1.1 ports, which will be fine for printing, but slow for file sharing. TP-Link has one high-speed USB2.0 port, which can be used to connect a regular USB2 hub and all of your devices.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the "Belkin Network USB Hub" might be the thing you are looking for?

I haven't heard of a specific wireless router which includes USB ports, although I'm ready to be proved wrong!